# React hooks update array of object

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, array, react.js, react-native

I have declared a react hook which will contain an array of object as follows:

```
const [rowDataTracker, setRowDataTracker] = useState([]);
```

Now I need to update the hook to basically create a payload as the following:

```
[
  {id: 100, payload: {field1: "value", field2: "value"}}, 
  {id: 105, payload: {field1: "value", field3: "value"}},
  {id: 109, payload: {field4: "value"}}
]
```

I need to check the following condition Before updating the hook:

- Need to first check if the **id** exists in the array or not
- if the **id** exists, then need to update/add the **filed** to the payload object
- if the **id** does not exist, add a new object to the array with **id** and the **field**

```html
const ifItemExist = (arr, item) => {
  return arr.findIndex((e) => e.id === item);
};
function storeEdit(rowId, field, newValue) {
  let itemIndex = ifItemExist(rowDataTracker, rowId);
  let newArr = [...rowDataTracker];
  if (itemIndex > -1) {
    newArr[itemIndex]["payload"][columnId] = newValue;
  } else {
    const obj = {
      itemNbr: rowId,
      payload: {
        [field]: newValue
      }
    };
    newArr.push(obj);
  }
  setRowDataTracker(newArr);
}
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to update a hook.
Any review and suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Mutation** You are *mutating* the existing state when you do

```
let newArr = [...rowDataTracker];
// ..
  newArr[itemIndex]["payload"][columnId] = newValue;
```

because spread syntax only creates a shallow copy of the array or object. This should never be done in React. (See end of answer for how to fix it - create the new `obj` no matter what, then either push it to the new array, or replace the existing object in the array, without mutating the existing object in the array)

**Dot notation** Most people prefer to read and write using dot notation in JS when possible - it's more concise and easier to read. ESLint rule: [`dot-notation`](https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/dot-notation). You can use `.payload` instead of `["payload"]`.

**Property/variable naming** The `rowId` refers to the same thing as the `itemNbr`, which looks to refer to the same thing as the `id` in the `rowDataTracker` array. It's good to be consistent with variable names and properties when possible - consider picking one and sticking with it. If you use the variable name `itemNbr`, you can use it  shorthand in the object literal:

```
const obj = {
  itemNbr,
  // ...
```

**`id` or `itemNbr` or both**? You check against the `id` property in `rowDataTracker` in `ifItemExist`, but you push to the same array with a property named `itemNbr`. This looks very likely to be  a typo. You probably meant to push an object with an `id` property, or you wanted to check against the `itemNbr` property instead.

**Misleading function name** `ifItemExist` doesn't return a boolean indicating if an item exists - it returns the **index** of the possibly-existing item. Maybe call it `getItemIndex`.

**[Prefer `const`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6)** over `let` when the variable name doesn't need to be reassigned.

**In all**:

```
const getItemIndex = (arr, item) => {
  return arr.findIndex((e) => e.id === item);
};

function storeEdit(id, field, newValue) {
  const itemIndex = getItemIndex(rowDataTracker, id);
  const obj = {
    id,
    payload: {
      ...rowDataTracker[itemIndex]?.payload,
      [field]: newValue
    }
  };
  if (itemIndex === -1) {
    setRowDataTracker([...rowDataTracker, obj]);
    return;
  }
  const newArr = [...rowDataTracker];
  newArr[itemIndex] = obj;
  setRowDataTracker(newArr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed review. It is helpful.